# Running out of INT datatype for PRIMARY KEY in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

So i have a table in SQL that has a PRIMARY KEY Column with an INT datatype. the column is almost running out of INT values as i already have up to 2Billion Plus values in that column. I try to resolve this by changing the datatype to BigInt but the navigator crashed. Please what is the best Approach of resolving this?

Comment: Given that integers are 4 bytes and can store values into the billions, 2 million rows does not seem like an excessive number.

Comment: actually i meant 2billion plus

Comment: The INTEGER data type of SQLite can take up to 8 bytes if needed with a max value of 2^63 - 1 = ‭9223372036854775807‬, so you're not even close.

Comment: You really should use INTEGER, not INT, for the PK in the future: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit to number of rows is 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 if you make use of negative values, beyond what most (any?) devices can store at 1 bytes per row (no row would be just 1 byte they would be more bytes).

For more details
    [Limits In SQLite - Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table](https://sqlite.org/limits.html)

*I try to resolve this by changing the datatype to BigInt but the navigator crashed*

As for datatype that does not affect matters except when retrieving data, which is a subtle issue that can be got around by using implicit or explicit CASTing. The other except for datatype is if using INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (implicit or explicit but specifically INTEGER not INT or BIGINT) which makes the column a rowid alias and there can only store integer value. In all other columns except rowid and an alias of the rowid any type of value can be stored.

For more details [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

*Please what is the best Approach of resolving this?*
From SQLite perspective nothing, there is no issue.